# Prove the following functions are not continuous at c.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$1) c = 1; f(x) = x, 0 < x ≤ 1;
          f(x) = 3 − x, 1 < x < 2.
$

my solutions:

$1)$ $a)$function $f$ is defined at $x=1$ since $f(1)=1$

$b)$the left hand limit $\lim f(x) = \lim x = 1$
    the right hand limit
    $\lim f(x) = \lim 3-x = 2$

since left and right hand limits are not equal lim(fx) does not exit
 and condition (2) is not satisfied. Thus function f is not continious at x=1

(condition 2 is from notes in class)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: okay thanks for the help